# How to create a local properties file for a Java Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I have a Spring Boot project where I store some variables such as server credentials in a properties file. Now, I do not want those credentials to be checked into source control, so I want them to be in a local properties file that is automatically read if it exists. My normal properties file is an `application.yml`.

I have already tried it with the following files:

- `local.properties`
- `local.application.yml`
- `application-local.yml`

However, in all of those cases, the values that I had written in the local properties file were completely ignored. If I have those same values in the normal `application.yml`, they worked just fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just name it `application.yml` and it will be read next to the other one. Or name it `application-local.yml` and start your application with `--spring.profiles.active=local`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The oversimplified answer is that the file needs to be called `application-default.yml`. Then, Spring Boot automatically recognizes and uses it without the need for additional configuration.

The complete answer revolves around a concept known as "Profiles". In Spring, applications (and tests) are run with profiles that allow for different configurations. Spring will automatically look for configuration files named `application-[Profile Name].yml` (and the respective `.properties`-file variants) and load them. When no profile is explicitly specified, the profile is `default`. Thus Spring loads the `application-default.yml` without the need for further configuration.

This is a powerful tool and can be leveraged for many different purposes. To set a specific profile on the application level, the property `spring.profiles.active` needs to be set. This can for example be used to have different settings for staging and release environments by having an `application-staging.yml` and an `application-release.yml`, and then setting the environment variable `spring.profiles.active` on the respective environment to `staging` and `release` respectively.

It is also possible to set an active profile specifically for test classes using the annotation `@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "[Profile Name]")`. This allows for using different properties file for different tests.

Answer (score 0):

To configure which application properties to use,
first is to set

```
spring.profiles.active=in-application
```

in your properties file

and to define

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=in-application
```

in the VM options

For example the properties file name is application-dev.properties
then will be

```
spring.profiles.active=dev,in-application

-Dspring.profiles.active=dev,in-application
```